# Using RecursiveIteratorIterator to iterate through an array that is a property value

Tags: php

I'm developing a content iterator that should recurse into arrays and return each value as a separate iteration. Here's a stripped version of my class:

```
class ContentIterator extends \RecursiveIteratorIterator
{
    private $_ordinal = 0;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct(new \RecursiveArrayIterator(\func_get_args()));
    }

    public function key()
    {
        return $this->_ordinal;
    }

    public function getChildren()
    {
        $current = $this->current();
        if (property_exists($current,'array')) return new \RecursiveArrayIterator(array_values($current->array()));
        throw new \Exception('Shouldn\'t reach here!');
    }

    public function hasChildren()
    {
        $current = $this->current();
        return \is_array($current) || $current instanceof \Traversable;
    }

    public function next()
    {
        parent::next();
        ++$this->_ordinal;
    }

    public function rewind()
    {
        parent::rewind();
        $this->_ordinal = 0;
    }

}
```

Here's the test:

```
class TestSource {
  public $array = ['a','b','c'];
}

foreach (new ContentIterator(new TestSource) as $key => $value) 
    echo "$key => ".json_encode($value)."\n";
```

The test should produce this result:

```
0 => "a"
1 => "b"
2 => "c"
```

It actually produces this result:

```
0 => ["a","b","c"]
```

How do I fix ContentIterator to make it perform correctly?

(Yes, I'm aware I can use ArrayIterator or RecursiveArrayIterator to recurse through the array. That's not the point here.)

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7b913577b4406ee3046f4965baab642a840f4d5d ?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is a bug in PHP 7.0.x that causes this result. The sandbox abover demonstrates that it works in PH 5.6.x and 7.1.x.